# Upload multiple images on Firebase using NodeJS and Busboy

Tags: node.js, firebase, image-uploading, busboy

I created function for uploading a single image on Firebase using NodeJS and Busboy, which returns image url. Allowed image extensions are only `.jpg` and `.png`. It will generate random filename and create filepath with `storageBucket`.

However, I am struggling to refactor this function, so I could upload multiple images. I tried several attempts, but no luck. It should return array of image urls, if all images were uploaded successfully.

Here is my function with single image upload:

```
const { admin, db } = require("./admin");
const config = require("./config");

exports.uploadImage = (req, res, url, folder) => {
    const BusBoy = require("busboy");
    const path = require("path");
    const os = require("os");
    const fs = require("fs");

    const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

    let imageFileName;
    let imageToBeUploaded = {};

    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
        if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ error: "Wrong file type submitted!" });
        }
        // Getting extension of any image
        const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[
            filename.split(".").length - 1
        ];
        // Setting filename
        imageFileName = `${Math.round(
            Math.random() * 1000000000
        )}.${imageExtension}`;
        // Creating path
        const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
        imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });
    busboy.on("finish", () => {
        admin
            .storage()
            .bucket()
            .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
                destination: `${folder}/${imageFileName}`,
                resumable: false,
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
                    }
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o${folder}%2F${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
                if (url === `/users/${req.user.alias}`) {
                    return db.doc(`${url}`).update({ imageUrl });
                } else {
                    return res.json({ imageUrl });
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                return res.json({
                    message: "Image uploaded successfully!"
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
            });
    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

Any suggestions how to move on?

Answer (score 3):

Samuel Vera's answer is almost correct. There are some typos and a logic error when push to **imageUrls** array.

Here, the complete code fixed:

```
const BusBoy = require('busboy');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');

let fields = {};

const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: request.headers });

let imageFileName = {};
let imagesToUpload = [];
let imageToAdd = {};
let imageUrls = [];

busboy.on('field', (fieldname, fieldvalue) => {
    fields[fieldname] = fieldvalue;
});

busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && mimetype !== 'image/png') {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: 'Wrong file type submitted!' });
    }

    // Getting extension of any image
    const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[
        filename.split('.').length - 1
    ];

    // Setting filename
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000)}.${imageExtension}`;

    // Creating path
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToAdd = {
        imageFileName,
        filepath,
        mimetype,
    };

    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    //Add the image to the array
    imagesToUpload.push(imageToAdd);
});

busboy.on('finish', async () => {
    let promises = [];

    imagesToUpload.forEach((imageToBeUploaded) => {
        imageUrls.push(
            `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageToBeUploaded.imageFileName}?alt=media`
        );
        promises.push(
            admin
                .storage()
                .bucket()
                .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
                    resumable: false,
                    metadata: {
                        metadata: {
                            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype,
                        },
                    },
                })
        );
    });

    try {
        await Promise.all(promises);
        
        return response.json({
            message: `Images URL: ${imageUrls}`,
        });
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

busboy.end(request.rawBody);
```

Anyway, thank you Samuel :)

Answer (score 2):

You've the code almost done, all you've got to do is to create an array of promises and wait for all to resolve.

```
let imageFileName = {}
let imagesToUpload = []
let imageToAdd = {}
//This triggers for each file type that comes in the form data
busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: "Wrong file type submitted!" });
    }
    // Getting extension of any image
    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[
        filename.split(".").length - 1
    ];
    // Setting filename
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
        Math.random() * 1000000000
    )}.${imageExtension}`;
    // Creating path
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToAdd = { 
       imageFileName
       filepath, 
       mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    //Add the image to the array
    imagesToUpload.push(imageToAdd);
   });

busboy.on("finish", () => {
        let promises = []
        let imageUrls = []
        imagesToUpload.forEach(imageToBeUploaded => { 
imageUrls.push(`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o${folder}%2F${imageFileName}?alt=media`)
                    promises.push(admin
                        .storage()
                        .bucket()
                        .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
                             destination: `${folder}/${imageFileName}`,
                             resumable: false,
                             metadata: {
                                 metadata: {
                                     contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
                                 }
                             }
                         }))
                })
          try{      
              await Promises.all(resolve)
              res.status(200).json({msg: 'Successfully uploaded all images', imageUrls})
}catch(err){ res.status(500).json(err) }
            });
        busboy.end(req.rawBody);
```

With that you should be able to upload them all, it's just a matter of putting all promises inside an array and use the `Promise.all` method to wait for them to resolve. I made it with async/await because that's how I've been doing it but I suppose you would have no problem in doing it with the callbacks.

Also the code is messy but that's mostly because I dont know how to use this text editor, I hope you can still understand it

Comment: Thanks! It's working! Please add 'async' in your function so I can accept this answer, otherwise, it throws an error.

Comment: I have already use async to my function but it's still giving me an error - 
https://pastebin.com/YKgCitMu